# Find combination of groups and letters

Tags: c, combinations, permutation, letter

I have to find a combination of groups of letters, second letter in first group should be the same as first letter in second group etc.

For example, solution for this group: `AA, CB, AC, BA, BD, DB`
is this: `CB, BD, DB, BA, AA, AC`

I have this code so far, it works, but if there is a lot of groups, it takes ages to compute. I need to make it more efficient.

In the input file, there's this input

```
10
C D
B C
B B
B B
D B
B B
C A
A B
B D
D C
```

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void permutation(char group[][2], int buffer, int sum) {
    int i, j;
    char temp;

    if (buffer == sum && group[1][1] == group[sum][2]) {
        for (i = 1; i < sum; i++)
            if (group[i][2] != group[i+1][1]) break;

        if (i == sum) {
            FILE *output;
            output = fopen("output.txt", "a");
            for (j = 1; j <= sum; j++) {
                fprintf(output, "%c %c\n", group[j][1], group[j][2]);
            }
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        for (i = buffer; i <= sum; i++) {
            temp = group[buffer][1];
            group[buffer][1] = group[i][1];
            group[i][1] = temp;
            temp = group[buffer][2];
            group[buffer][2] = group[i][2];
            group[i][2] = temp;

            permutation(group, buffer + 1, sum);

            temp = group[buffer][1];
            group[buffer][1] = group[i][1];
            group[i][1] = temp;
            temp = group[buffer][2];
            group[buffer][2] = group[i][2];
            group[i][2] = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *input;

    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    int sum, i;

    fscanf(input, "%d", &sum);

    char group[sum][2];

    for (i = 1; i <= sum; i++) {
        fscanf(input, "%s", &group[i][1]);
        fscanf(input, "%s", &group[i][2]);
    }

    permutation(group, 1, sum);
}
```

**EDIT** So I have made some changes in my program (thanks to your help, I'm very new to programming so I'm sorry for mistakes), I use permutations no more and I'm just finding path. It works well, but now my input has 100000 groups and it takes a lot of time once again (about 2 hours and I need to make it done in 1 hour in maximal). I will probably have to do that in other way once again xD Any ideas ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find(char group[][2], int buffer, int sum, int path[]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < buffer; j++)
            if (path[j] == i)
                break;
        if (buffer == 0 ||
            (group[path[buffer-1]][1] == group[i][0] && buffer == j)) {
            printf("%d\n", buffer); // just for me to know what program is currently computing
            path[buffer] = i;
            find(group, buffer + 1, sum, path);
            if (path[sum-1] != 0)
                return;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (input != NULL) {
        int sum, i;

        fscanf(input, "%d", &sum);
        char group[sum][2];
        int path[sum];

        for (i = 0; i < sum; i++)
            fscanf(input, " %c %c", &group[i][0], &group[i][1]);
        for (i = 0; i < sum;i++)
            path[i] = 0;

        find(group, 0, sum, path);

        FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "a");
        for (i = 0; i < sum; i++)
            fprintf(output, "%c %c\n", group[path[i]][0], group[path[i]][1]);
    } else
        printf("Input file was not found.");
}
```

Comment: Please stop editing the posted code incrementally from the answers and comments suggestions, it makes the whole discussion inconsistent.

Comment: I suggest you share all necessary code so that one can run the program and test performance. You should at least do your best to make it easier for us to help. Your question is not a coding problem, it's a performance problem; and this is a coding Q&A site, not a performance site. How much time does it take for your test to complete?

Comment: Here you have input with 50 pairs: 50
F C
A F
E F
E E
C E
F E
B F
F E
E E
E E
E E
E B
F F
F C
C A
F E
E A
B F
E F
F C
F E
A A
E E
E E
E E
E E
B C
A E
C E
C E
E B
C E
E E
E F
E F
E C
A D
E E
E E
D A
E B
C C
E E
E E
F A
A C
C E
E B
B D
D F


My program is now running something about 3 hours, still haven't found correct combination. I think it should be programmed in other way, could somebody tell me some advice how to program it somehow else ?

Comment: Can you post a link to this large test file?

Comment: Here you go http://speedding.sweb.cz/input.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new code has some problems:

- `find` is defined asa returning `int`, but you return nothing.  You indeed do not test if you have found a complete path, fully relying on the assumption that there is at least one and that you have found it.
- You do not test for path closure.  You may find a closed path by chance, but you may also produce an unclosed path.
- Using 2 loops to find the unused pairs is less efficient than using a temporary array `used[sum]`.
- The first pair is always the first, so you can simplify the `find` function a little.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find(char group[][2], int buffer, int sum, int path[], unsigned char used[]) {
    int i;
    char last = group[path[buffer-1]][1];

    if (buffer == sum)
        return last == group[0][0];

    for (i = 1; i < sum; i++) {
        if (!used[i] && last == group[i][0]) {
            path[buffer] = i;
            used[i] = 1;
            if (find(group, buffer + 1, sum, path, used))
                return 1;
            used[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (input != NULL) {
        int sum = 0, i;

        fscanf(input, "%d", &sum);

        char group[sum][2];
        int path[sum];
        unsigned char used[sum];

        for (i = 0; i < sum; i++)
            fscanf(input, " %c %c", &group[i][0], &group[i][1]);

        path[0] = 0;  // always start at first element
        used[0] = 1;
        for (i = 1; i < sum; i++)
            used[i] = 0;

        if (find(group, 1, sum, path, used)) {
            FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "a");
            for (i = 0; i < sum; i++)
                fprintf(output, "%c %c\n", group[path[i]][0], group[path[i]][1]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Input file was not found.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: I tested this new version with your large input file: it crashes on my laptop.  The previous version with the `permutation` functions works like a charm, producing the complete path in 0.060 seconds.  So there is a complete path and something is wrong with this `find` function.

There are few differences between the algorithms:

- `permutation` uses less stack space: a single automatic array of size n*2 (200k) versus 3 automatic arrays total size `n*(sizeof(int) + 3)` (700k).
- `permutation` uses fewer variables, so recursion uses less stack space, but both probably use more than 1 MB of stack space to recurse 100000 times.
- `find` does more scans, where `permutation` swaps `group` pairs and always snaps the next one directly.

I reimplemented `find` without recursion and finally got it to produce a complete path.  It is a different one and it takes much longer to compute, 3.5 seconds.

For larger input files, you definitely should not use recursion and you should even allocate the arrays from the heap with `malloc`.

Here is the non recursive code, using heap memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int find(const char group[][2], int sum, int path[]) {
    path[0] = 0;
    if (sum <= 1)
        return group[0][1] == group[0][0];

    unsigned char *used = calloc((size_t)sum, sizeof(*used));

    for (int buffer = 1, i = 1;; i++) {
        if (i == sum) {
            --buffer;
            if (buffer == 0) {
                free(used);
                return 0;
            }
            i = path[buffer];
            used[i] = 0;
        } else
        if (!used[i] && group[path[buffer-1]][1] == group[i][0]) {
            path[buffer] = i;
            if (buffer == sum - 1) {
                if (group[i][1] == group[0][0]) {
                    free(used);
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                buffer++;
                used[i] = 1;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (input != NULL) {
        int sum = 0, i;

        fscanf(input, "%d", &sum);

        char (*group)[2] = calloc((size_t)sum, sizeof(*group));
        int *path = calloc((size_t)sum, sizeof(*path));

        for (i = 0; i < sum; i++)
            fscanf(input, " %c %c", &group[i][0], &group[i][1]);

        if (find(group, sum, path)) {
            FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "a");
            for (i = 0; i < sum; i++)
                fprintf(output, "%c %c\n", group[path[i]][0], group[path[i]][1]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Input file was not found.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once, I wish I was such a good programmer as you are. Thank you, master.

Comment: @Speedding: keep working hard, it takes a long time, constantly honing your skills.  I still learn new things and get humbled everyday, after 42 years (yes, 42!).  Stackoverflow is a great place for thist, so is https://projecteuler.net/

Comment: @Speedding: oops!  I don't know if my code solved the problem on your system, but it failed for the 100k input file on mine.  I investigated this and came to a strong conclusion: recursion uses too much stack space for a recursive approach and possibly for automatic arrays as well.  I updated the answer with a non recursive version that uses the heap.

Answer (score 2):

In C array indices start at 0, so an array of size `N` has valid indices from `0` to `N-1`. In the code above you are accessing the array `group` out of bounds, since it has size `2` (valid indices are therefore `0` and `1`), yet you are trying to access indices `1` and `2`.

Either change:

```
char group[sum][2];
```

to:

```
char group[sum][3];
```

or use indices `0`/`1` rather than `1`/`2`.

Note also that your code lacks error checking, e.g. on the call to `fopen`.

Comment: I don't have problem with functionality. I have problem with time of computing. If there's more than 50 groups, it takes hours to compute (there's 50! combinations). I need to make it done in a few minutes

Comment: Actually you *do* have a "problem with functionality" - your code has serious bugs and will therefore exhibit Undefined Behaviour and will probably give incorrect results. You need to fix your code before you try to optimise it.

Comment: Now I have changed code to
    char group[sum][3];
Still takes hours to compute.

Comment: In that case you should update your question appropriately, otherwise you will be wasting other people's time. (Also, how do you know it still takes "hours to compute" ? You only applied the bug fix in the last two minutes ?).

Comment: You still have to fix the loop in `main()` (i = 0; i < sum...). And better have the second dimension of size 2 and index with 0 and 1

Comment: Use `0` based indices for rows and columns in the `group` matrix.  Also use `fscanf(input, " %c", &group[i][1]);` to read 1 character at a time, ignoring spaces and **not** storing the null byte beyond the end of the subarray.

Answer (score 1):

Your program as several issues:

- you use 1 based indexing, which causes confusion and leads to referencing arrays and subarrays beyond their defined ends.
- you parse the input with `fscanf` using the `%s` specifier: this is unsafe and will write 2 bytes for each of your inputs, writing beyond the end of each subarray and beyond the end of the last array.

You already know how to fix these, preferably by using 0 based indexing

Your algorithm is **very** ineffective, complexity `O(n!)` because you enumerate all possible permutations and check for validity only on complete permutations.  You can drastically improve the performance by only enumerating permutations which already verify the constraint for their initial elements.  The complexity is substantially lower, still quadratic but `n` is quite small.

Here is a modified version of your code that does this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int permutation(char group[][2], int buffer, int sum) {
    if (buffer == sum)
        return group[sum-1][1] == group[0][0];

    for (int i = buffer; i < sum; i++) {
        if (group[buffer-1][1] == group[i][0]) {
            char temp = group[buffer][0];
            group[buffer][0] = group[i][0];
            group[i][0] = temp;
            temp = group[buffer][1];
            group[buffer][1] = group[i][1];
            group[i][1] = temp;

            if (permutation(group, buffer + 1, sum))
                return 1;

            temp = group[buffer][0];
            group[buffer][0] = group[i][0];
            group[i][0] = temp;
            temp = group[buffer][1];
            group[buffer][1] = group[i][1];
            group[i][1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int sum, i;

    if (input != NULL) {
        if (fscanf(input, "%d", &sum) != 1 || sum <= 0) {
            printf("invalid number of pairs\n");
            fclose(input);
            return 1;
        }

        char group[sum][2];

        for (i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
            if (fscanf(input, " %c %c", &group[i][0], &group[i][1]) != 2) {
                printf("incorrect input for pair number %d\n", i);
                fclose(input);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        fclose(input);
        if (permutation(group, 1, sum)) {
            FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "a");
            if (output == NULL) {
                printf("cannot open output file\n");
                return 2;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
                fprintf(output, "%c %c\n", group[i][0], group[i][1]);
            }
            fclose(output);
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("complete path not found\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("cannot open input file\n");
    return 2;
}
```

I modified other aspects of the code to improve efficiency and reusability:

- input is checked for validity.
- the recursive function stops and returns 1 when it finds a complete path. This allows the program to continue whether it found the path or not.
- output is handled from the `main` function for consistency.

The above code solves the problem for the specified input with n=50 in **less than 0.002 seconds** on my laptop. It prints `F C C E E F F E E E E E E E E E E B B F F E E A A F F C C A A A A E E F F C C E E E E E E E E E E B B C C E E E E F F E E F F F F E E C C E E E E E E B B F F A A D D A A C C C C E E E E E E B B D D F`

**EDIT** I realized that, since you are looking for a full closed path, you do not need to try different possibilities for the first pair.  `main` can call `permutation` with `1` instead of `0` and the `permutation` can be simplified as `buffer` can never be `0`.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to use all of given groups and they CAN'T repeat :(
I also know, there will always be solution.

Comment: @Speedding: I don't understand your constraint.  I generate exactly the same permutations is the same order, the speedup comes from early pruning of impossible solutions.  Do you mean the identity pairs cannot be repeated immediately and must be used after another part of the path?  That's easy to add to the algorithm.

Comment: No, that's ok. Try to solve this input
6
A A
C B
A C
B A
B D
D B
... It will print out some bullshits.

Comment: @Speedding: my bad, I was presumptuous and did not correctly assess the consequences of the change of method: constructing the path into a separate array requires an extra array to keep track of which pair is already used. I restored your original idea and just added the early pruning, checking for path continuity before recursion.  It is still very fast ans solves the problems correctly.

Comment: Thank you. You are the best !! ^^